# Difference between merkwürdig and seltsam

Tags: difference, usage, adjective, synonym

I was wondering if there is a difference in the usage between *merkwürdig* and 
*seltsam*. My German to English dictionary translates both to *peculiar* or *odd*. Can I use them interchangably?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Colloquially, they are usually interchangeable. In any case, you should *consider* the differences.

Since *[merkwürdig](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/merkw%C3%BCrdig)* derives from *merken* (remember) and *würdig* (worthy), it characterizes something deserving to be remembered, or at least to be noticed (*bemerken*). There’s a synonym called *bemerkenswert* which still conveys the original meaning.

On the other hand, *[seltsam](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?lemma=seltsam)* means that something’s seldom (*selten*) and that it’s odd and unusual. Today, it’s used like “odd” in English (like in “That’s odd” or “the child exhibits an odd behavior”).

If you look up their etymologies, you’ll realize that they originally had a very distinct meaning. In everyday use, you usually don’t have to ponder the differences.

Comment: I totally agree, but *bemerkenswert* is not a synonym (anymore), as you say yourself in your last paragraph.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the literal meanings, I would think *merkwürdig* is closer to the English term *curious* (`That's a curious way to make a cake`) when applied to a phenomenon while *seltsam* is more like *unusual* or *awkward*. At the same time, common meaning has probably left the logic, as often happens in language.

Comment: Yes, _merkwürdig_ is closer to the English term _curious_, but it still has a negative touch. I would translate _curious_, in a positive or neutral meaning, as _interessant_ or _eigenartig_.

Answer (score 0):

There is no important difference.
You can use them synonymously.